# How do I deploy twisted on only a certain directory?

Tags: python, proxy, centos, twisted, reverse-proxy

I'm wondering if you can deploy a twisted server to only listen on a certain directory (exp: example.com/twisted)?
Here's my code if it helps:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server
from twisted.python import log

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.example.com', 80, ''.encode("utf-8")))
reactor.listenTCP(80, site)
reactor.run()
```

I'm running this on my CentOS VPS btw, thanks!

Comment: So, what should happen if the root of the website is accessed?

Comment: just nothing, I want to be able to run multiple proxy servers on different paths/directory simultaneously (example.com/website1, example.com/website2, example.com/website3 etc..)